# Why do people consider multivalued solutions of differential equations?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, complex-manifolds

The nature of the question is heuristic. If we have, say, a nonsingular complex manifold, what is the interest in knowing solutions of a differential equation of its universal cover instead of on the manifold itself? Why did people come up with this problem in the first place?

I'll be thankful for any kind of input on this.

Comment: Its an easier first step.  You don't have to worry about a solution evolving as it goes around the loop and hits you from the other direction.  Once you have it, you can tweak its parameters so the solution that has been round the loop matches your original solution.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: A cheap answer would be: because the latter (solutions on the manifold) don't exist in general. If your solution turns out to be multivariate, it simply cannot be solved on the manifold. And there are very basic examples (like logarithm or square root) that behave like this. Is it close to what you had in mind?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz absolutely. Is there a reasonable criterion to decide whether a multivalued solution is actually single valued, i.e. defined on the base manifold?

Comment: For example, in the case of linear differential equations on Riemann surfaces (i.e. in the case of ODEs) the solution space on the universal cover seems to be easily described as a finite dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space. I agree with @Empy2 that this makes life considerably easier as a first step, but how can we draw meaningful information for the solutions on the base space out of this?